# PostgreSQL query to calculate occurrence of values in a jsonb data type column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, subquery

I am working on creating a PostgreSQL query to address the following scenarios:

- I have a column with the jsonb data type.
- Within this column, there is a data object containing two properties: labels and number. For example: "data": {"label": "SOME_LABEL", "number": 1}.
- The objective is to sum up the 'number' property for all records with the same 'label'.
- For instance:

  - Record 1: column info -> "data": {"label": "SOME_LABEL_1", "number": 1}
  - Record 2: column info -> "data": {"label": "SOME_LABEL_2", "number": 1}
  - Record 3: column info -> "data": {"label": "SOME_LABEL_1", "number": 80}
  - Record 4: column info -> "data": {"label": "SOME_LABEL_2", "number": 10}
  - Record 5: column info -> "data": {"label": "SOME_LABEL_3", "number": 1}
- After summing up, the results need to be ordered by the 'label' with the highest total 'number' value.
- The desired output would look something like this:

  - Row 1: label: "SOME_LABEL_1", sum: 81
  - Row 2: label: "SOME_LABEL_2", sum: 11
  - Row 3: label: "SOME_LABEL_3", sum: 1

I would highly appreciate any assistance you could provide on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the desired result using a query like:

```
SELECT data ->> 'label' AS label, SUM((data ->> 'number')::numeric) AS total_sum
FROM my_table
GROUP BY data ->> 'label'
ORDER BY total_sum DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Group by "label" and get the sum of "number", then select record with max sum

Comment: Remove `limit 1` to get the desired output.